# Accessing a variable from a function inside a function?

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
function create_sort_callback($criteria)
{
  return function($a, $b)
  {
    $a = $a[$criteria];
    $b = $b[$criteria];

    return ($a == $b ? 0 : (($a < $b) ? -1 : 1));
  };
}
```

It turns out I can't access `$criteria` from within the inner function. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
function create_sort_callback($criteria)
{
  return function($a, $b) use($criteria)
  {
    $a = $a[$criteria];
    $b = $b[$criteria];

    return ($a == $b ? 0 : (($a < $b) ? -1 : 1));
  };
}
```

You need using closures http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Answer (score 0):

Use the `use` keyword.

```
function create_sort_callback($criteria)
{
  return function($a, $b) use ($criteria)
  {
    $a = $a[$criteria];
    $b = $b[$criteria];

    return ($a == $b ? 0 : (($a < $b) ? -1 : 1));
  };
}
```